# How to check the ButtonGroup Id and change the other button according to that ButtonGroup id

Tags: c++, qt

I have `QButtonGroup` in which i have added 5 `QPushButton` and have set the id for all `QPushButton`. Now when id is 2, i want to setSize of id 1 and 3 to (100,100).

```
QButtonGroup *button = new QButtonGroup;
button.addButton(button1,1);
button.addButton(button2,2);
..
..
button.addButton(button5,5);
```

Now i want when `button2` has focus then i want to set its size to (150,150) and `button1` and `button3` size to (100,100).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have every button handle it own focus/focus-lost event and resize itself? So mouse enters button grows automatically, mouse leaves button shrinks. Can be easiy integrated using the button-own events.

Comment: i did like that but for each button the code is become lengthy. So i thought to use Buttongroup so that i can write particular function and by palying with its id i can do my work

Comment: Just create a subclass of QPushButton and implement your grow/shrink code once for using the subclass your buttons will be instanced of.

Comment: @Rupesh So what if some other button is in focus,then also you need to do the same that is the focused button should be of 150*150 and all other buttons of 100*100???Please clarify?

Comment: yes, when one button is having focus then its size should be 150*150 and rest of all other button should have size 100*100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it,so here is what you need to do:
In my Dlg.h

```
  class MyPushButton : public QPushButton
  {
    public:

    MyPushButton(QString ButtonName, QWidget *parent);
    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* event);
    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent* event);
  };
```

In my Dlg.cpp:

```
   MyPushButton::MyPushButton(QString ButtonName, QWidget *parent)
   :QPushButton(ButtonName,parent)
   {
   }

   void MyPushButton::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* event)
   {
     this->setMinimumHeight(150);
     this->setMinimumWidth(150);
   }

   void MyPushButton::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent* event)
   {
     this->setMinimumHeight(100);
     this->setMinimumWidth(100);
   }
```

You dont need QButtonGroup.Now all you need to do is use "MyPushButton" class and set the default height and width of the buttons to 100 *100.Let me know if you have any doubts.

MyMainWindow.cpp ,its ctor:

```
  MyMainWindow::MyMainWindow(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
  :QMainWindow(parent, flags)
 {
   ui.setupUi(this);
   this->setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("MainWindow"));
   this->resize(250, 250);

   QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(this);

//Create QPushButtons
button1 = new MyPushButton("Button 1" , centralWidget);
button1->setMinimumHeight(100);
button1->setMinimumWidth(100);
button2 = new MyPushButton("Button 2" , centralWidget);
button2->setMinimumHeight(100);
button2->setMinimumWidth(100);
button3 = new MyPushButton("Button 3" , centralWidget);
button3->setMinimumHeight(100);
button3->setMinimumWidth(100);
button4 = new MyPushButton("Button 4" , centralWidget);
button4->setMinimumHeight(100);
button4->setMinimumWidth(100);

QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(centralWidget);
layout->addWidget(button1);
layout->addWidget(button2);
layout->addWidget(button3);
layout->addWidget(button4);
layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetNoConstraint);
this->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
    }
```

In MyMainWindow.h

```
   class MyMainWindow: public QMainWindow
  {
 Q_OBJECT

   public:
 MyMainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
 ~MyMainWindow();
public slots:
    void FileNew(int i);
    void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *e);

   private:
 Ui::StClass ui;
 MyPushButton* button1;
 MyPushButton* button2;
 MyPushButton* button3;
 MyPushButton* button4;
  };
```

Comment: I have mainWindow class which i am calling by defining constructor. So should i define one more class like u have define

Comment: Yes ofcourse ...and by having mainWindow class you mean :you have a class that is inheriting QMainWindow rit?

Comment: Please see above,i have given code of my class which i have inherited from QMainWindow

Comment: Now all you have to do is to make an object of MyMainWinow and then with that object call show() in your main

Comment: Your answer is correct but i want to use buttons outside the constructor too. It means i will use my buttons in KeyReleaseEvent too so now it will throw error as i am not declaring it in header file. Kindly help what to do

Comment: @Rupesh Which ctor are you talking about ??Anways if i understand correctly ,you are talking about the MainWindow class in that case you can make it as member variable of your MainWindow class.And the KeyReleaseEvent is in which class?Please ask your question terms of the above example

Comment: In myMainWindow class i want to add button which we are adding by using MyPushButton. Now i want to access these button outside of myMainWindow Constructor. It means i will use button in KeyreleaseEvent then as it is outside the declaration as you have defined it in under myMainWIndow. So it will throw error

Comment: You can make it as member variable ..refer my MainWindow.h and it is a C++ basic concept.

Comment: I know i did like that only bro. But it is throwing an error: 'MyPushButton' does not name a type. That's why i asked you.

Comment: Where are you declaring your PushButton class?Just include the header file in MyMainWindow.h